# Hats on profile block access to mod tools

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, moderator-tools, winter-bash

[image]

Note that I can barely click on "Mod", and can't even read the number in brown indicating the number of flags on the account. A pretty minor thing overall, but still annoying. This appeared on [The Final Frontier (Space)](http://thefinalfrontier.stackexchange.com), by the way. Through some experimentation, it seems to primarily affect beta sites. I've confirmed that it only affects users with long names (I should shorten my username someday...)

Comment: You must be joking.... working while Winter Bash is running? There are several hats to get! HATS! You know?

Comment: @Braiam: That's my secret agenda for posting this question:-)

Comment: This is SE's way to suggest that moderator's take a winter break. :)

Comment: Off-topic: That URL alias is great :D

Comment: @Doorknob冰: A sneaky way to bring in more traffic to my site:-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed now, thanks. This is only a problem if stuff gets pushed down because of lots of moderator links *and* a long username. If the bobble hat covers the mod links, we now shift them to the left:

[image: screenshot of the moderator links having moved to the left of the hat]

Comment: I should get a hat for reporting a bug relating to hats;-)

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto And I should fix bugs [six minutes faster](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/speedy-delivery).

Comment: Looks like I did end up getting a hat for it after all... Thanks!