# Hat icon appearing in top left of chat room, not over user picture

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, winter-bash-2015

Why is the hat for bjb568's user profile in the top left of the screen rather than over his user icon?

[image: Hat Icon]

It seems to be attached to that line of messages. This is what happens when I scroll up:

[image]

The HTML for the page as I see it is as follows:

```html
<div class="user-container user-237813 monologue">
    <a class="signature user-237813" href="/users/237813/bjb568">
        <div class="hat" style="float: left; display: block; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: visible; position: relative; left: -22px; top: -610px;" data-hatid="36">
            <img width="20" height="24" style="display: block;" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%20height%3D%2224%22%20viewBox%3D%2234.25%2022.375%20123.5%20147.25%22%20width%3D%2220%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%20200%20200%22%3E%3Cg%20transform%3D%22%20translate(18.941264749935144%2019.1339115880603)%20scale(0.7705873525006486)%22%3E%3Cpolygon%20points%3D%22129.7%201...6.5%2018.65%22%20fill%3D%22%23020202%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22m57%2075.04c-1.087%200-1.697%200.576-1.825%200.817%200.128%200.24%200.738%200.817%201.825%200.817%201.088%200%201.7-0.577%201.826-0.817-0.13-0.24-0.74-0.82-1.83-0.82%22%20fill%3D%22%23ccc%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22m143%2075.04c-1.086%200-1.699%200.576-1.824%200.817%200.125%200.24%200.738%200.817%201.824%200.817s1.699-0.577%201.826-0.817c-0.1-0.24-0.7-0.82-1.8-0.82%22%20fill%3D%22%23ccc%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E">
        </div>
        <div class="tiny-signature" style="display: none;">
        <div class="avatar avatar-16">
            <div class="username">bjb568</div>
        </div>
        <div class="avatar avatar-32 clear-both" style="display: block;">
            <div class="username" style="display: block;">bjb568</div>
            <div class="flair" style="display: block;" title="3741">3741</div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="messages">
        <div class="clear-both" style="height: 0px;"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because SE's front end is all borked? :p not my fault

Comment: The irony that it was you that it happened to wasn't lost on me

Answer (score 4):

This was similar to the problem I describe [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271041/115866), except that the hat is applied to an invisible avatar. In that case, the measurement that decides on the exact position of the hat will output garbage, and that's what causes that weird hat position. This is prevented now.

As I said in that other answer: This fix is deployed, but only applies to chat pages that were loaded after the build (in other words: after you reload, this shouldn't happen anymore).