# Hats borked in chat: Hat appears in top-right corner of user image

Tags: bug, chat, winter-bash-2015

Possibly related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271020/hat-icon-appearing-in-top-left-of-chat-room-not-over-user-picture), I noticed a bit ago that occasionally there is an issue with the hats in chat. Here's a screenshot to demonstrate:

[image: Bug capture 0]

As you can see, @AidanMueller's hat is fine in the top image, and is scrunched into the top-right portion of the image in the bottom large one. In the smaller one towards the middle, it seems fine.

As new messages were sent, the issue apparently is only in that one image, here's a picture of the messages sent afterwards:

[image: Bug capture 1]

A quick note: reloading the page does fix the issue:

[image: Bug capture 2]

Comment: Here's a link to the chat where this occurred: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26215421#26215421