# Hats are placed in the top left screen corner if user icon (e.g. from facebook) is blocked from loading

Tags: bug, status-declined, facebook, winter-bash

I use Firefox with the "Disconnect" add-on which has the feature to block e.g. content from Facebook etc.

Some of the SE users' icons are from Facebook so if we block that, these icons do not load and are invisible, which is acceptable though.

However, during Winter Bash, there are hats added to the icons. Unfortunately, if the original icon is blocked from loading, the hat just gets placed in the top left corner of the visible screen:

[image]

This is a bug, although it's only a minor one because it probably doesn't affect too many users. I would like to suggest to hide the hat if the icon did not load (yet or at all) instead of placing it in the top left corner.

Related issue (from chat, not main sites): [Hat icon appearing in top left of chat room, not over user picture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271020/hat-icon-appearing-in-top-left-of-chat-room-not-over-user-picture)

Comment: What does that Disconnect add-on do? it blocks and removes the `<img>` tag or so?

Comment: working fine if you use Policeman instead. I block images from gravatar, the hats stay in the expected position.

Comment: The problem isn't *just* that the image is not loading, but that the entire element is being deleted off the page. This is unexpected behavior for our script that we do not support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I'd count that as a bug at all - you are not using the site with a supported configuration, so you have broken something.

My opinion would be that if you want to have all the features work as they should, you need to go with a supported browser configuration.